# Time after last jump and waiting time before the next jump of Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times, levy-processes

Consider $N =(N_t)_{t\geq0}$ a Poisson process  of intensity $\lambda > 0$ and $(T_n)_{n\geq 1}$ its jump instants.

Then consider  for all $t \geq 0$, $Z_t = t- T_{N_t} \mathbb 1 _{\{ t \geq T_1\}}$, the time after the first jump of $N$, and $W_t = T_{N_t+1} -t$, the waiting time before the next jump of $N$.

I would like to obtain $\mathbb P \{ Z_t >z, W_t >w \}$.

$$ P \{ Z_t >z, W_t >w \} = P \{  T_{N_t} \mathbb 1 _{\{ t \geq T_1\}} < t-z, T_{N_t+1}  > t+w \} 
\\ = \sum_{n\geq 0} P \{  T_{n} \mathbb 1 _{\{ t \geq T_1\}} < t-z, T_{n+1}  > t+w \ | \ N_t=n \}$$

I guess it's necessary to use the fact $T_n \sim \Gamma(n,\lambda), \ \forall n\geq 1 $ or $(T_{n+1} -T_n) \overset{\text{iid}}{\sim}  \mathcal E (\lambda), \ \forall n\geq 0  $, but I don't see how to manage to it.

Any advices are appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\mathbb P \{ Z_t >z, W_t >w \} = $ no events in $(t-z, t+w)$

Comment: @mike: Absolutely! Many thanks.